# Show results in an ordered way in html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to html and i want to consult you about an issue i have.

I have a json object with this structure (only example):

```
  {
     [{
         ServerName: "Server1",
         TestResults: [{
             Name: "Test1",
             ErrorMessage: "",
             Success: true
             },
             Name: "Test1", ErrorMessage: "", Success: true
         }]
     }, {
         ServerName: "Server2",
         TestResults: [{
             Name: "Test1",
             ErrorMessage: "",
             Success: true
             },
             Name: "Test1", ErrorMessage: "", Success: true
         }]
    }]
 }
```

My javascript code gets this object and suppose to create from it something like this:

```
         <ul>
            <lh>ServerName</lh>
            <li><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></li>
            <lh>ServerName2</lh>
            <li><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></li>
            .....
        </ul>
```

I want to know how do i create such a list that each `'lh'` has a line of its own,
and each 2-3 `'li'` are in the same line.

Can you help me find the best solution for it?

P.S - I am not using a table because it has some problems in jquery mobile that sometimes make it not fitted for the page size.

Comment: ***lh*** ? That does not seem valid HTML to me

Comment: @mplungjan http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/listheader.html

Comment: I know, but in what universe is HTML3 used as valid markup?

Comment: It is a list header in the Unordered list.
But that is not the way i want to concentrate on.
The idea that i am looking to implement correctly is the structure i showed in my question.
If you think i can use 'li' as header for server name it is fine by me.

Comment: is your question about generating the html or styling it?

Comment: Both.
Because i am kind of new to html , i would be happy to hear both styling ideas or event ideas for a better way to do it in the html.

Comment: Hey,

What if i have 8 tests for each server and i want only 2 tests in each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a definition list (`<dl>`) and style it with css. Add a unique class to your list to avoid conflict with other CSS styles: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZ938/)

**HTML**

```
<dl class="yourclass">
    <dt>ServerName</dt>
    <dd><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></dd>
    <dt>ServerName2</dt>
    <dd><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="#" type="button">TestName</a></dd>
</dl>
```

**CSS**

```
dl.yourclass dd {
    display:inline;
}
```

Comment: Partly working for me.
But as i said in my comment above, this is the right direction for me.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can add some css for that:

```
ul>lh{
    display: block;
}
ul>li{
    display: inline;
}
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/584LA/).

Comment: It is not working in my side.
I am working with JqueryMobile css also (and need it).
Is there a correct way to do what you suggested without removing this css?

Comment: @DevTraveler It's very likely the styles in that css got priority. You can refer to [CSS Rule Priorities](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/html_priorities_css.htm) for how to raise the priority. A shortcut way is to give the `ul` an `id` (e.g. `id="serverList"`) and specify that in css. I updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/584LA/1/) to demonstrate this. Can you have a try?

Comment: It seems to be the direction of using it.
I think i just need to learn some more about the options i have in css files.

Comment: Hey,

What if i have 8 tests for each server and i want only 2 tests in each line?

Comment: #Gildor can you please help?